Moderator engaging in Abusive behavior
What do you all think?
While posting Python change double slash to single , the user https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze

Made no change or suggestion other to answer/assist with the question but stated I was "confused" and did have a problem. I elaborated that the out put was not what I was after. and provide text from the original post
Deceze then suggested a method that "should" be what I want. It was not and I supplied the output to compair the goal from the original post.
Deceze then states: "Yes. That’s what you want to see. End of story."

"End of story" can be considered Bullying and/or Harassment Hostile comments under Abusive behavior policy
I restated my goal output to clear any confusion
4. Deceze - "For the same reason you wrote it with four backslashes into your code"
At this point, my post was edited by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar CC BY-SA 4.0 for formatting
My post was then closed. I then had to reedit my post to the original text to request it to be reopened.
I'm unsure if Barmar and Deceze are working together or the same person but the speed at which an incorrect snappy comment was delivered and then an unjust moderation (to put it lightly) was issued leads me to believe there is a close coloration.
It now appears as I'm writing this that Deceze is still trying to convince me my desired output is present even after I show it is not.
In the entire process I have received down voting and cant see how it is justified.

In your provided code, software_path = "\\\\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1" is not a literal string, meaning that you have to escape backslashes. The actual value contains one/two slashes, not two/four: \\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1. This means that your code does not show the output that you claim it does, and was correctly closed as being "not reproducible". Just edit your question with a minimal reproducible example that does show this "four quote" issue (probably with a string literal) and submit for reopening.

As for the other points brought up: (1) no, Barmar and Deceze are not the same person. New questions get edited quickly since they appear at the top of the questions page when sorted by "Newest". (2) People downvote for whatever reason, it may or may not be justified. Seeing as your question was closed, I'd say it is. (3) "End of story", while blunt, isn't rude or abusive, and definitely isn't directed towards you as an insult.

Perhaps you mean the output or line 5: print (software_path)? Which does show "\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1" and match what I was describing as the sub process not seeing the same value but "\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1" instead.

Line 5 shows that your question is not reproduceable. The print statement proves that software_path already contains the correct string: \\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1. If this was a correct MRE, it would instead printed the incorrectly escaped string: \\\\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1. If your path is being modified when calling check_output, that's a completely different question.

It's like if a question asked "why does 5+10 equal 20?", with the code that "shows" this behaviour as being x = 5+10; print(x); with the console displaying 15. The provided example doesn't show the incorrect behaviour, so it's not reproduceable.

I see the print statement has the correct value. That print statement is only for reference and testing. The actually part that matters is in the sub process. When its called it does NOT see it as it was printed. I'm not sure what MRE is
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['powershell', '-Command', '\\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

In my opinion, claiming abusive behavior when there is none, is itself abusive behavior

@Slippy as deceze already commented on your main site question what the error shows you is the string literal representation, the value of the string is what you're expecting and asking for. It would be better if you show us the actual output you got and potentially your powershell script.

Hmmm I was under the impression it was python not bash. But its being writing in Visual Studio  Code. Here is a short version that I'm reproducing and unable to advance.
import subprocess
software_path = "\\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1"
print (software_path)
item =subprocess.check_output([f"powershell", f"-Command", software_path ], shell=False)

Powershell can take any number of slashes for its filepaths. Heck, even cat 'Desktop\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\TestDocument.txt' worked for me. Even with a ps1 script, powershell -Command "C:\\\\Users\\\\username\\\\Desktop\\\\test.ps1" works as well. I cannot reproduce your issue.

@Slippy That error message adds escape sequences to what it prints so that non-printable characters will be visible, i.e. a byte with ASCII code 1 would be printed as \x01.  Because of this backslashes also need to be escaped when it outputs.  So a single backslash in the source string will be printed as two backslashes in the error message.

I don think PowerShell is the problem. I think is sub process but am unsure

One thing that surprised me about this post is deceze really IS a moderator.

dbush- that is intresting and news to me, i will try real path to see it it works.

I'm still getting the same results with a real path, but the point of this post was to judge the handling of the original post. You all have already worked more on it and presented ideas without closing or attempted gaslighting (I'm referencing the "End of Story" comment in regards to a question) . User " user4581301" discovering that " deceze" is a moderator would explain the two working together and not being the same person.    So should it have been closed? Or should more constructive question been asked to gain an understanding?

In its current form, yes, it should be closed. However, questions being closed do not mean that they should stay closed. Questions are closed (rather than outright deleted) when they are unanswerable as-is, but not unsalvageable. Yours was closed because the double backslash thing wasn't even an issue; but why not edit it into what the problem actually was about: running powershell -Command "script.ps1" over a network share? Assuming it wouldn't be a duplicate, of course... along with a minimal reproduceable example (python script, file structure, powershell version?)

""End of story" can be considered Bullying and/or Harassment Hostile comments under Abusive behavior policy" no.

"I'm unsure if Barmar and Deceze are working together or the same person" I'm unsure if you're a terrorist or a troll. See how easy it is to throw any and all accusations regardless of merit then phrasing them like you did? Do you consider what I said rude or abusive? If so, how does that reflect on what you yourself said? If not, then you should really re-think it anyway.

@VLAZ , clearly they are all Skrulls.

Cover blown, I repeat, cover blown! Retreat!

The reason user4581301 is surprised you're actually talking about a moderator, is that questions like these are normally about normal users erroneously called "moderators" after they close-voted a post.

"I'm still getting the same results with a real path" - yes, that's exactly it. Multiple people were trying to tell you that you already had a real path. That's why you're getting the same results: because the problem isn't with the string handling.

"You all have already worked more on it and presented ideas without closing or attempted gaslighting" - there was no "gaslighting". Just because someone is telling you that the output is correct, when you think it is wrong, does not mean that someone else is trying to convince you that a wrong output is correct. It could also mean - and did mean here - that what you expected was not the right thing to expect.

@ipodtouch0218 the path isn't being modified when calling subprocess.check_output; it's being *displayed with escape sequences in an error message - because it's part of the repr of a list that was passed.

Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't directly calling out a user especially over something controversial harrasment,

@Ethan it is at the very least, very unkind.

Harassment generally requires a pattern. It take a hell of an offence for a single instance to qualify as harassment.

This will be more bluntness, but trust me, it's for your own good.
These kinds of questions pop up regularly. Especially Windows file paths in Python are a prime attractor for misinterpretations. Because people don't get escape sequences; until they eventually do. You currently do not. Sorry to say. The output you're presenting in your question is exactly as would be expected. There is nothing wrong with it. You're looking at output in which the backslashes are escaped. You cannot read it literally, you must interpret it as an escaped string literal.
Further evidence that you don't know what you're talking about (sorry, being blunt, but it's really better this way):

a = str(software_path)


This does absolutely nothing, software_path already is a string, putting it through str doesn't do anything.

software_path.replace('\\','\' )


That's actually a syntax error.

software_path.encode().decode('unicode_escape')


That's just randomly throwing spaghetti at the wall.

No, you're clearly just trying random things. But your question is actually an XY problem.
With these kinds of questions, I'll predict you based on experience that some good meaning samaritans will come along who equally don't understand escape sequences, and they'll propose a lot more random spaghetti, none of which works. But you'd be following those along because it looks like the solution you're attempting, but it'll never go anywhere. And a lone comment like "you're doing it wrong~" will be totally ignored, because it's not what you want to hear.
Closing the question is actually doing you a solid. Because it forces you to confront the actual problem, eventually, after much teeth pulling and complaining on Meta. At this point we have no idea what the actual problem is, because you're not forthcoming with the actual error message you're encountering, but keep insisting on your XY solution.
You're asking experts here. Accept their expert opinion and realise you're tilting against the wrong windmill. Then go back and provide the actual information in your question we need to actually help you.

This is essentially the Reddit experience. People welcome questions with open arms, not like that toxic Stack Overflow that closes all questions, and then you get a whole bunch of spaghetti flinging. Fun, but you end up having to wash tomato sauce out of your clothes and that just made matters worse rather than better.

There doesn't seem to have been any abuse here. It looks more like a misunderstanding.
The question is rightfully closed. It can be evidenced by a fact that Barmar's edit accidentally changed the meaning of your question. We need to understand more what that "from" and "to" mean. What you have in your code is a path with single slashes and one double slash at the start. The path is however double escaped for Python string literal syntax. So what exactly do you mean when you say you want to go from one to another?
Barmar is in no way working with deceze nor are they the same person. They are just two users who interacted with your question.

To understand the situation properly, we need to start with the code, the errors, and your apparent conclusions.
First, please start by thinking carefully about what happens at the start of the code. You have:
software_path = "\\\\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1"
print (software_path)

And you get the result:
\\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1

Because you did not ask about this, I assume that this result matches your expectations. Therefore, I should be able to conclude:

You already understood that the string (the actual string, not your code) contains two backslashes at the start, and one backslash between the folder names - not four and two, respectively.

You already understood that you should write the code that way, with the extra backslashes, in order to get the string you want. (In fact, it would have worked without them, simply because \d and \s are not real escape sequences; this is deprecated, and will become an error in some future Python version.)


If you didn't actually understand these things, then you need to be more deliberate about the code that you're writing, and start by looking up the Q&A for the things you actually need to know about, rather than skipping ahead and only trying to ask when you encounter an error message. There is no substitute for actual understanding.
But assuming I'm reading the situation correctly, then you also should know that your opening query doesn't make any sense:

I'm trying to turn \\\\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1
into \\domain\dir1\dir2\dir3\script.ps1

Well, no, obviously you aren't trying to turn the first thing into the second thing, because you don't have that first thing to begin with.
And since you already have a string that contains one backslash between the folder names, there is obviously not any "change" to make, and no question to ask. Right?
So, my guess is that you got to this situation because you were trying to use the string for something else, and got an error message:
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['powershell', '-Command', '\\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

And my guess is that you saw \\domain\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\script.ps1 and thought "oh, that must be the cause of the error. Wait, why are there two backslashes in between? Shouldn't it be only one?"
But, of course, the string really does use single backslashes. The error message looks like this because it's showing you the string as part of a list, not printing it.
And, of course, the actual reason for the Powershell failure is something completely different. For example, it could be that you aren't supposed to replace the double (what you called "quadruple") backslash at the start of the string because it's supposed to be a UNC path. Or maybe you're missing a drive letter. Or maybe the path is fine but there just isn't actually a script file in the place where you expected it. Or maybe it even found the script fine, and something went wrong while running it.
It's your job to investigate those possibilities before asking. If you aren't at a level where you can do that, you aren't in a place where you can ask a question suitable for Stack Overflow. We don't debug issues, provide tech support, or teach; we answer questions - that are, generally, either about one specific detail of how something works, or about how to do one specific, atomic thing.

If any of the above doesn't make sense to you, then you have asked the wrong question. Instead of asking "how do I do this?", you should have asked "why do I get this result?". This is a common duplicate, and you should read it:
Why do backslashes appear twice?

But assuming I'm still on the right track - that you understood how backslash escaping works in Python string literals, but got an error message from using one, and expected it to be reported back to you without escaping -

then you were, indeed, confused.

Which is to say, you were temporarily not thinking clearly or logically.
It happens to the best of us. I've been programming for about 35 years and volunteered countless hours on the Internet teaching Python concepts to beginners, and it still happens to me all the time.
There's nothing remotely abusive about pointing this out when it happens. (When it isn't actually what happened, it's even giving you credit for understanding things that you might not have.)
The output of the string really was exactly what you were after, and if you expected different output, then you realistically should have known why that expectation was not reasonable. The other reason why this output would be "not what you were after" is because of the script itself not working. The situation here was your fault because you did not take the appropriate action to verify the other aspects of the situation - for example, whether you could successfully run the script from a Powershell prompt directly.
What deceze proposed you should do (i.e., not attempt to process the string) was in fact completely correct. This was accompanied by correctly telling you that the string shown in the result looked like it's supposed to. This was the "end of story" because there isn't any more to the issue of the string escaping - and any issue you had with running a Powershell command from within your program is completely separate.
The comment "For the same reason you wrote it with four backslashes into your code" was a helpful hint that should have cued you to recognize your confusion: if you have to write four backslashes in the code to get a string that actually has two backslashes, then of course a code-formatted output of a string that actually has one backslash, will display two.
There is nothing at all about this phrasing that could be considered "bullying" or "harassment".
You've been getting further downvotes because a) you apparently aren't listening to what you've been told (which tends to draw more attention to your posts), and b) your question doesn't help contribute to the site (which means people who see your question are liable to downvote it). If you hover over the downvote arrow, you can see the site's reminder text for why questions are downvoted.
It's important to understand that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, help desk or anything else like that. We are building a Q&A library, and votes are content rating according to that goal. Good questions are those which help make the library better for everyone - by being something that someone else with a clear, simple, direct question in mind, which is the same question as yours, can realistically find with a search engine and subsequently get an answer.
